# Distinct LINQ by dateOfCreation

Tags: c#, linq

I have my diagram of database
[image]

As you can see, PipelineJobStatus is a aggregation - has two keys, first key can repeat itself:

> PipelineID|JobSTatusID

6                 |    3

6         |    6

6         |    8

7         |    1

7         |    2

8         |    9

I want to show this exactly the same view (merge), but with the latest CreatedDateTime for Distinct values.
my linq:

```
  private IQueryable<StatusPipelineMerge> wholeResults()
    {
        var query2 = (
           from pjs in db.PipelineJobStatus
           from pipe in db.Pipelines
               .Where(pipe => pipe.PipelineID == pjs.PipelineID).DefaultIfEmpty()
           from status in db.JobStatus
               .Where(statuses => statuses.JobStatusID == pjs.JobStatusID).DefaultIfEmpty()
           from fco in db.FCOes
                .Where(fcoes => fcoes.FCOID == pipe.FCOID)
           from client in db.Clients
           .Where(clients => clients.ClientID == pipe.ClientID)
           group new { pipe.CreatedTimeStamp }
          by new
          {
              status.JobStatusName,
              pipe.PipelineID,
              pipe.ClientID,
              client.ClientName,
              fco.NameFCO,
              fco.FCOID,
              pipe.Employee.Name,
              pipe.Employee.Surname,
              pipe.CommentPipeline,
              pipe.CreatedBy,
              pipe.CreatedTimeStamp,
              pipe.ModifiedTimeStamp,
              pipe.ProjectValueHr,
              pipe.ProjectValueMoney
          } into g

           orderby g.Key.PipelineID ascending

           select new StatusPipelineMerge
           {

               PipelineID = g.Key.PipelineID
               ,
               ProjectValueHr = g.Key.ProjectValueHr
               ,
               ProjectValueMoney = g.Key.ProjectValueMoney
               ,
               CommentPipeline = g.Key.CommentPipeline
               ,
               ClientName = g.Key.ClientName
               ,
               FCOName = g.Key.NameFCO
               ,
               FCOID = g.Key.FCOID
               ,
               ClientID = g.Key.ClientID
               ,
               CreatedTimeStamp = g.Key.CreatedTimeStamp
               ,
               ModifiedTimeStamp = g.Key.ModifiedTimeStamp
               ,
               CreatedBy = g.Key.CreatedBy
               ,
               //CreatedNameSurname = g.Key.Employee.Name + " " + g.Key.Employee.Surname

               JobStatusName = g.Key.JobStatusName
           }

            );

        return (query2);
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, it's strongly recommended to use stored procedures in such difficult cases. And one hint: did you try to use `join` keyword? It won't change the behaviour, but seems to have much better performance. And did you try to write `descending` in `orderby` statement?

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy Yes, I am aware of it about JOIN method is much better. Maybe I will use stored procedures..it is maybe easier then linq (I'm new in LINQ)..thanks anyway

Comment: You have several problems here, for example, you mix pure LINQ and `Method Chain` methods, it's a bad practice. Linq is good when you have a simple logic `db.SomeTable.Where(Predicate).Select(Something)`. It helps to not write a lot of dumb requests or stored procedures. And LINQ generates a very good code in such cases. But when you write a complex logic with multiple joins, groupings etc, .Net produce very slow and inefficient code, hardly to debug and so on. It's not a silver bullet for all cases, so good luck in inplementing it in SQL :)

Comment: Will try via SQL, but I got that feeling, that I am very close (although inefficient code) to the solution. Probably somewhere I need to put Distinct() method or domething :)